# During Trying to Connect Printer to home network and issues show up that aren't being resolved

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, laptop, printer

Trying to connect wireless printer to laptop and these showed up: virtual wi-fi miniport adapters:_03, _04, _05 with a notification which said they were missing drivers. I tried to locate online but it seemed none found or no resolution and do not think I need them, but really have no idea, personally.  Some say these adapters are not necessary for installing this printer for my laptop and my husband's iPad. Please confirm if correct, and tell me what to do now, please. FYI: I have HP Pavilion, am using Windows 8.1, and printer is Epson Workforce WF-2650. I hope you can help me. Intend to use printer at this time to print, scan, and copy.
(Am not using fax; not certain will not use it in the future: not sure if this has anything to do with this issue or not)

Answer (score 0):

Start by making sure the printer is connected to your network. The easiest way is to use WPS (if your WiFi router supports it). See the [User's Manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd4/cpd40869.pdf), starting on page 32.

Next, you need to install the driver on the PC. The easiest way to do this is to use the driver DVD that came with the printer. It should find the printer on the network and do the rest. Alternatively you can download the driver from [Epson's support site](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/WorkForce-Series/Epson-WorkForce-WF-2650/s/SPT_C11CD77201?review-filter=Windows+8+64-bit). This link is for Win 8, 64 bit. Select a different O/S if needed.

Finally, to set it up on the iPad, the User's Manual (pg 27) recommends the use of the iPrint Mobile App. Download Epson iPrint from the App Store and make sure the iPad is connected to the same wireless network.

Finally, if you need to scan, install scan drivers are available on the DVD or from the same Epson support page. If you downloaded the Driver Combo, scan drivers will be included. There is also an OCR utility, to convert the scan into text characters (a raw scan is just a bitmap, i.e. a picture, without text).